# write to file Android

Tags: android, text-files

I've tried this code to write to a file in ana Android project:

```
FileOutputStream fOut;
try {
    fOut = openFileOutput("text.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String str = "data";
    fOut.write(str.getBytes());
    fOut.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the problem is that I don't know if this code creates my text.txt file and I don't knomw where it saves it...can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is saved in `/data/data/your.package.name/files`. This directory is not visible to file managers (without root). Although, if you want to save it to the sd card then add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And save the file to the sd card by setting a location first.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

an example of log file:

```
public static BufferedWriter out;
private static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private DLog(){}

private static void createFileOnDevice(Boolean append) throws IOException {
    /*
     * Function to initially create the log file and it also writes the time
     * of creation to file.
     */
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (root!=null && root.exists() && root.canWrite()) {
        File LogFile = new File(root, "LOG.txt");
        FileWriter LogWriter = new FileWriter(LogFile, append);
        out = new BufferedWriter(LogWriter);

    }
}

public static void addText(String tag, String message) {

    if(out==null){
        try {
            createFileOnDevice(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        if(out==null)return;
        out.write("LOG: "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        out.write(" \t ");
        out.write(tag.toUpperCase()+": "+message + "\n");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

don't forget to add appropriate permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it doesn't create my text.txt file...
How can I check if my sdcard is writable?maybe this is the problem..

Comment: can you add break point before checking this condition 
if (root!=null && root.exists() && root.canWrite()) 
and see whether you have root is not null and it is writable

Answer (score 0):

You may specify the path

```
...
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/my_folder/";
fOut = openFileOutput(dir+"text.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
...
```

this would save to `sdcard/my_folder/text.txt`

also you need to define the write permission in you `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```